# Brother SDK for iPhone/iPad Ver. 3.1.1 Roll Types

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, printing

I am trying to print from my app to the Brother QL series label printers. When I try to print, I can print when I have a roll of type **Tape** in the printer. However, when I try to print to a roll of type **Label** I cannot get anything to print. I get back the error code:

ERROR_WRONG_LABEL_ 
Incorrect roll type
-41

I have tried a bunch of different settings and I cannot figure out what settings will allow me to print with that type of roll. Additionally I have read through their SDK documentation and cannot find any information about this issue.

Comment: I'm also struggling with this error. Did you get anywhere with this @nathan-perry

Comment: I was never able to get the Brother SDK to work. I ended up rewriting this library into swift: https://github.com/pklaus/brother_ql.

Answer (score 3):

After some digging here are the paper sizes you can use for the QL family of printers. e.g.

```swift
let printInfo = BRPtouchPrintInfo()
printInfo.strPaperName = "17mmx54"
printInfo.nPrintMode = PRINT_FIT
printInfo.nOrientation = ORI_LANDSCAPE
printInfo.nHorizontalAlign = ALIGN_CENTER
printInfo.nVerticalAlign = ALIGN_MIDDLE
printInfo.nAutoCutFlag = 1
printInfo.nAutoCutCopies = 1
```

### Brother QL-810W

- Custom
- 12mm
- 29mm
- 38mm
- 50mm
- 54mm
- 62mm
- 62mmRB
- 17mmx54mm
- 17mmx87mm
- 23mmx23mm
- 29mmx42mm
- 29mmx90mm
- 38mmx90mm
- 39mmx48mm
- 52mmx29mm
- 62mmx29mm
- 62mmx100mm
- 60mmx86mm
- 54mmx29mm

### Brother QL-820NWB

- Custom
- 12mm
- 29mm
- 38mm
- 50mm
- 54mm
- 62mm
- 62mmRB
- 17mmx54mm
- 17mmx87mm
- 23mmx23mm
- 29mmx42mm
- 29mmx90mm
- 38mmx90mm
- 39mmx48mm
- 52mmx29mm
- 62mmx29mm
- 62mmx100mm
- 60mmx86mm
- 54mmx29mm

### Brother QL-1110NWB

- Custom
- 12mm
- 29mm
- 38mm
- 50mm
- 54mm
- 62mm
- 102mm
- 103mm
- 17mmx54
- 17mmx87
- 23mmx23mm
- 29mmx42mm
- 29mmx90mm
- 38mmx90mm
- 39mmx48
- 52mmx29mm
- 60mmx86mm
- 62mmx29mm
- 62mmx100mm
- 102mmx51mm
- 102mmx152mm
- 103mmx164mm

### Brother QL-1115NWB

- Custom
- 12mm
- 29mm
- 38mm
- 50mm
- 54mm
- 62mm
- 102mm
- 17mmx54
- 17mmx87
- 23mmx23mm
- 29mmx42mm
- 29mmx90mm
- 38mmx90mm
- 39mmx48
- 52mmx29mm
- 60mmx86mm
- 62mmx29mm
- 62mmx100mm
- 102mmx51mm
- 102mmx152mm
- DT 90mm
- DT 102mm
- DT 102mmx51mm
- DT 102mmx152mm

Answer (score 1):

I got mine printing using 62mmRB. 62mm gives me the save error -41 as you get. It seems I had red & black roll in.

Comment: I faced the same issue, how can you detect if the inserted roll is 62mm or 62mmRB?

Comment: As far as I remember it says red black on the back. Or just try changing the roll type in the code and see if it works. I don’t think you can detect it code wise.

Answer (score 0):

This issue cause is you set wrong/incorrect paper name. I changed my paper name, the issue resolved. I shared my code for you reference.

```
    let printInfo = BRPtouchPrintInfo()
    printInfo.strPaperName = "29mmx90mm"
    printInfo.nPrintMode = PRINT_FIT_TO_PAGE
    printInfo.nOrientation = ORI_LANDSCAPE
    printInfo.nHorizontalAlign = ALIGN_CENTER
    printInfo.nVerticalAlign = ALIGN_MIDDLE
    printInfo.nAutoCutFlag = 1
    printInfo.nAutoCutCopies = 1
```